# Fetchtype.Eager is giving NullPointerException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss

I'm using a Bidirectional OnetoMany relationship using hibernate JPA.

I am getting a null pointer exception even though I'm using fetchtype.Eager and the same piece of code works in one rest method but not the other?

**CODE**

*User*

```
public class Users implements Serializable {
     /** other fields  **/
     @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "users", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
     private Collection<Tokens> tokensCollection;

     /** getters and setters for other fields **/

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Tokens> getTokensCollection() {
        return tokensCollection;
    }

    public void setTokensCollection(Tokens token) {
        if (!token.getUser().equals(this.Userid)) {
             token.setUser(this);
        }
        this.tokensCollection.add(token);
    }
}
```

*Token*

```
public class Tokens implements Serializable {
     /** other fields  **/

     @JoinColumn(name = "userid", referencedColumnName = "userid")
     @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
     private Users users;


     /** getters and setters for other fields **/

    @XmlTransient
    public Users getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Users users) {
        if (!users.getTokensCollection().contains(this)) {
             users.getTokensCollection().add(this);
        }
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

I have two rest methods, one has a JMS queue to set up users and inserts a temporary token once the user has been inserted (not sure because I was getting a NPE when I was using the setters and getters so I tried to insert the user first then create a token then match them up as I will show below). The other an authentication point that inserts a token upon successful authorization. I'm open to change the way in which I have set up my entities if it's not best practice or the performance issues are devastating.

*Insert Methods*

```
   Users user = rfl.getUserByUsername(username);
   Tokens tkn = new Tokens();
   tkn.setJWT(token);
   tkn.setUsers(user);

   //not sure if this is making a difference cos I read somewhere that lazily loading is only impacted once you iterate over the collection but it doesn't make a difference cos a) im using eager and b) it works in one place but not the other

   Collection<Tokens> tokenss = user.getTokensCollection();
   for (Tokens token1 : tokenss) {
        System.out.println("User:" + token1.getUsers());
   }

   //rfl is my ejb facade responsible for entity management i.e. merge, persist, remove, find, flush
   rfl.edit(user);
```

**LOG**

```
2015-08-24 19:29:31,241 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401)) java.lang.NullPointerException

2015-08-24 19:29:31,241 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at ejb.Tokens.setUsers(Tokens.java:125)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,242 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at ejb.RegisterUserQueue.onMessage(RegisterUserQueue.java:72)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,242 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,242 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,243 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,243 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,243 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,244 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,244 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,244 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,245 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,245 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,246 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,246 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,246 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,247 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,247 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,247 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,248 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,248 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,248 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,249 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,249 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:55)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,250 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,250 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,250 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,251 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,251 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,252 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,252 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,252 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,253 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,253 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,253 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,254 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:251)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,254 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:342)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,254 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,255 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,255 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,255 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,256 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,256 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,256 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:95)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,257 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,257 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,258 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,258 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,258 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,259 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,260 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,260 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,261 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,262 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.messagedriven.MessageDrivenComponentDescription$5$1.processInvocation(MessageDrivenComponentDescription.java:211)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,262 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,263 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,263 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,264 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:326)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,264 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:448)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,264 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,265 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,265 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:326)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,266 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,266 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,266 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,267 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:185)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,267 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:182)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,267 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,268 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,268 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,269 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at ejb.RegisterUserQueue$$$view107.onMessage(Unknown Source)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,269 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,269 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,270 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,270 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,270 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.inflow.MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.doInvoke(MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.java:139)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,271 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.inflow.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:73)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,271 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at ejb.RegisterUserQueue$$$endpoint19.onMessage(Unknown Source)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,272 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.hornetq.ra.inflow.HornetQMessageHandler.onMessage(HornetQMessageHandler.java:321)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,272 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.callOnMessage(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1116)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,272 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.access$500(ClientConsumerImpl.java:56)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,273 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl$Runner.run(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1251)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,273 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at org.hornetq.utils.OrderedExecutorFactory$OrderedExecutor$1.run(OrderedExecutorFactory.java:104)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,273 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,274 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)

2015-08-24 19:29:31,274 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-357 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-934440401))   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

P.s. I opted for Eager here because I assume a user won't have too many tokens, I may change to Lazy down the line but I have other fields that will be Lazily loaded so it's irrelevant to this question.

P.P.S I know that the user has been inserted because I have a line that logs the username of the gotten user just before the `tkn.setUser(newuser)` one of the other methods

Comment: Did you see the user isn't retrieved.

Comment: Hi nikpon, I edited my question to state that I do test to see if I am getting a user with this piece of code `LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "User, {0},  ", newrippler.getUsername());` and it logs the correct username!

Comment: It's not a `User` but the name of the user.

Comment: Sorry I am confused, can you elaborate more as to what you mean by "Did you see the user isn't retrieved". I assumed that if I get the username it means I should have the user object. Edit: in the database the user has been inserted so the JMS queue has inserted the user, when I get the user by username I get the user, but when I try to attach the user to the token it goes wrong as the log suggests. I am not sure if its something to do with hibernate

Comment: yes you might be confused because it's not obvious and needs to debug until you get the instance of the user.

Comment: But isn't the case that I have the user? when I make this call `Users newuser = rfl.getUserByUsername(users.getUsername());` and I then just say `System.out.println(newuser.getUsername());` that if the system does print the username I do have the user object and then to do this should work `tkn.setUsers(newUser);`

Comment: yes the last statement throws the error, but it isn't seen in the logs, so you need to wrap it in the try/catch block and print stacktrace. Then you can post it to the question.

Comment: I am wrapping it in a try and catch, that log is the output of the stacktrace `catch(JMSException ex){ ex.printStackTrace();}` the error from the jms is being cascaded down to the rest method and the log in my question shows the stacktrace, I tried to wrap the `tkn.setUser` in a try and catch but the stacktrace was the same as the log above.